# Activator.getDefault() gives null & The activator is invalid

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I created a simple plugin in eclipse. When I run the application after exporting it
I received the below error in log file.

org.osgi.framework.BundleException : The activator for bundle org.x.y.Activator for bundle org.x.y is invalid.

but after removing Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy

[The activator for bundle is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305307/the-activator-bundle-is-invalid)

It worked fine after export the problem now is the Activator.getDefault() gives null

Comment: "The activator is invalid" is a generic error message used by OSGi to wrap the lower level exceptions that were thrown when trying to start your bundle. Please post your full stack trace, or at least the lowest level exception. Dind the lowest line of the stack that starts with "caused by", and post that line along with everything that's below. This is the actual exception that's been encountered with your activator. As for "getDefault()" being null, this means your plugin has not been started. You should leave the activationPolicy in and fix the actual issue (the stack will help for that).