# Migrate from Eclipse 3.2 to 4.3 - RCP based application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I try to migrate my plugin from eclipse 3.2 to eclipse 4.3. I face some major error when starting the plugin.

I got this error message:

> The activator projectscheduler_final.Activator for bundle
>   ProjectScheduler_Final is invalid

My OSGi Manifest looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: ProjectScheduler_Final Plug-in
Bundle-SymbolicName: ProjectScheduler_Final; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-Activator: projectscheduler_final.Activator
Bundle-Localization: plugin
Bundle-ClassPath: mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.ui.forms
Eclipse-LazyStart: true
```

And my pluginxml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.2"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         id="application"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
      <application>
         <run
               class="projectscheduler_final.Application">
         </run>
      </application>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
      <perspective
            class="projectscheduler_final.Perspective"
            fixed="false"
            id="ProjectScheduler_Final.perspective"
            name="Perspective">
      </perspective>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
      <view
            name="View"
            class="projectscheduler_final.View"
            id="ProjectScheduler_Final.view">
      </view>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
      <editor
            class="projectscheduler_final.ProjectSchedulerEditor"
            default="false"
            id="TestEditor"
            icon="images/folder_table.png"
            name="Test Editor"/>
      <editor
            class="projectscheduler_final.ProjectSchedulerEditorCreateProject"
            default="false"
            icon="images/wand.png"
            id="CreateProject"
            name="Create project editor"/>
      <editor
            class="projectscheduler_final.ProjectSchedulerEditorCreateSubProject"
            default="false"
            icon="images/wand.png"
            id="CreateSubProject"
            name="Create subproject editor"/>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            id="ProjectScheduler Final.command1"
            name="ProjectScheduler Final.command1"/>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

I tried a few tutorials from Vogella and co. but nothing cleared the error. I checked the Names of the application etc. everything seems to be in place. It would be nice if anybody would have some hint or a pointer where I should take a closer look at..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved to problem adding ., to the `Bundle-ClassPath` in the MANIFEST.MF

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to switch the core dependencies to the new target platform.

Go to **plugin.xml** -> **Dependencies** -> Remove the **org.eclipse.ui**, **org.eclipse.core.runtime** and **org.eclipse.ui.forms** then **add them again**!

Secondly, remember to include all of your required plug-in from the **Debug Configurations** window.

Go there, go to **Plug-ins**, deselect **Target Platform**, click **Add Required Plug-ins**, click **Validate**, then **Apply** and run it.

Many things have changed since 3.2, so if this still doesn't work, migrate the app manually. Start from scratch and copy class by class. Ocassionally see if the app starts.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I already tried a semilar approach, now yours, but no success, so I will migrate it manually...

Comment: Did you try to extend your `Activator` from the new `org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin` ?

Comment: I already extend from "org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin"

Comment: Have you seen this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305307/the-activator-bundle-is-invalid